# PHP encryption and decryption with mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I have problems when encrypt the information in mySQL by using PHP. I am using below example and finally I can encrypt the content but when I am decrypt in other page, some strange words will shown.

Please help

**I am using below function to encrypt**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");

$key = md5('test');

function encrypt($string, $key) {
     $string = rtrim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,$string,MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
     return $string;
}

//connection
....
//connection

mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);

$sql="INSERT INTO db (name) VALUES ('".encrypt($name,$key)."')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
?>
```

**And using below function to decrypt**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");

$key = md5('test');

function decrypt($string, $key) {
     $string = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,$key,base64_encode($string),MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
     return $string;
}

//connection
....
//connection

mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

        $query = "SELECT * FROM db";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
            echo $row['name'] ;
            echo decrypt($row['name'],$key) ;
        }


?>
```

Input: `TEST`

**And the result of decrypt:**

`K704rW4crOuvpDZe/yZ2ums0btlo8hvpeyJr91V+Ycg=�x�_L��kR�^О�dMFH��7*�%Ίֶ���M_<��w���W�^ ��3M�"��Rk�`

Comment: The Input:
TEST | 
The Output:
UQJokP0OqdnWUj5fOkI7dST/DI5rbqNfCyutFK2QNVQ= | The strange words:
e�� �"�Rw��,X���%|�R2�>}n���`w1y4�!yO'0|��~�p����L{�xk;

Comment: Shouldn't your decrypt function be using `base64_decode()` instead of `base64_encode()`?

Comment: Thanks so much squeamish ossifrage! sorry for my stupid mistake

Answer (score -2):

here is an function to encrypte and decrypte string :

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
$output = false;

$encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
$secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
$secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';

// hash
$key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

// iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
$iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

if( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
    $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    $output = base64_encode($output);
}
else if( $action == 'decrypt' ){
    $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
}

return $output;
}
```

and you call it like this :

if you want to encrypt just pass it to a first param and the string in the second param like this :

```
$encryptedString = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', 'test');
```

and to decrypte :

```
$decrypte = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encryptedString);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot first. But the stange words turn to this: gsRdgNdjDi3r4YMnBGHw50OzeS0zqtwTUqppi4l3TKkcJpfxMkO75GBQE+6+4u7oMy7wFXyHXr7B0EQIovxdPw==

Comment: Unattributed copy from https://naveensnayak.com/2013/03/12/simple-php-encrypt-and-decrypt/